# Why do we have incomplete instantiation of types from the test method parameter - AutoFixture with AutoData

Tags: c#, autofixture

Using Autofixture 3.46 AutoData attribute from Autofixture.xUnit2 3.46, and xunit2, instantiating Sum in the test method parameter, I get an Xunit.sdk.EqualException from the Assert.

```
[Theory ]
[AutoData]
public void ShouldBeSum_AutoData(int a, int b, Sum uut )
{

    //problem
    int  residue = uut.Value; //not zero!
    //fix
    uut.Value = 0;

    //Arrange - in the parameter leads to problem
    // var uut =new Sum();

    //Act
    uut.Add(a);
    uut.Add(b);

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(a + b, uut.Value);

}
```

It seems the  property value of the new Sum instance is not set to  a default for the type (say zero) on instantiation- evidence the non zero value of 'residue'.

```
public class Sum
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public void Add(int number)
    {
        Value += number;
    }
}
```

Instantiation of the test target uut from the body (and with new) gives the expected  default initial property values.
So the uut class is incompletely instantiated from a parameter at present - it's your responsibility.

A fix on the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is by design. AutoFixture is designed to create *and fill data* into objects, so that's its default behaviour.

There are many ways in which you can disable *AutoProperties* in AutoFixture. In this particular example, the lightest fix is to apply the `[NoAutoProperties]` attribute to the `uut` argument:

```
[Theory, AutoData]
public void ShouldBeSum_AutoData(int a, int b, [NoAutoProperties]Sum uut)
{
    uut.Add(a);
    uut.Add(b);

    Assert.Equal(a + b, uut.Value); // Passes
}
```

There are other, more wholesale, ways of achieving the same result, though.

---

Finally, this ought to give pause to reflect on the design of `Sum`: is it appropriate that `Value` is a publicly modifiable property? Shouldn't the invariants of the `Sum` class be that `Value` is *guaranteed* to be the result of performing calculations with the class (i.e. by calling `Add`)?

Such a design could look like this:

```
public class Summer
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public void Add(int number)
    {
        Value += number;
    }
}
```

in which case the following test automatically passes:

```
[Theory, AutoData]
public void ShouldBeSum_AutoData(int a, int b, Summer uut)
{
    uut.Add(a);
    uut.Add(b);

    Assert.Equal(a + b, uut.Value); // Passes
}
```

AutoFixture was originally build as a tool for Test-Driven Development (TDD), and TDD is all about **feedback**. In the spirit of [GOOS](http://amzn.to/VI81bP), you should **listen to your tests**. If the tests are hard to write, you should consider your API design. **AutoFixture tends to amplify that sort of feedback**, so a good reaction to trouble with AutoFixture is to look at the SUT before looking at AutoFixture itself.